# Edit html content of the operation pages in GC

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

This may sound newbie-sh but I would like to edit the actual html that is rendered by Grocery-Crud in the add, edit and delete pages, in order to add some other elements (UI elements, just to make the page similar to the rest of the web app in which I'm using GC)

Any help on how to do this?

Comment: I don't know Grocery-Crud I'm afraid, so I could be completely off base, but do you need to do this server side, or could it be done client side in some sort of efficient manner?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Yes it can be done client-sided. It's just a problem of visual stuff, just to make the CRUD operation pages generated by GC more look-alike to the whole of the app.

Comment: Ahh gotcha bro. Again, I don't know this framework/lib, so I'm sorry if this is totally wrong, just going off my usual best practices in these sorts of situations. Does the documentation provide information on how to override the styles? This guy looks like he had the same issue as you and fixed it :)
http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/2102-using-custom-template/